# How does spark take care of the input and output of correlation computation

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have 200 JavaRDD, each of them has 80 elements (200*80). I do parallelize them and make them ready for the correlation. So here I suppose my data is arranged in 200 rows and 80 columns and after I run the correlation the result matrix I got is always a 80*80 covariance matrix. But in my case I'm trying to get a 200*200 result.

Did spark do it columns wise? when I did it this way, did spark take it as I have 80 objects to calculate the correlation?
If so, how should I change my code to finish the task in a preferred way?

```
    for (String v : list) {
        Vector vv = firstpartFunc(jsc,"filename");//this is another function which gives me a vector as output, also one of the 200 vectors that I want to do correlation later.
        vResult.add(vv);
        } // I check the dimension of vResult here, it has 200 rows and 80 columns.
    JavaRDD<Vector> data = jsc.parallelize(vResult);
    Matrix correlMatrix = Statistics.corr(data.rdd(), "pearson");//And then I got a result of 80*80, not 200*200 :(
```